# IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 10

Tags: python, numpy

How should I fix this error?

```
dhidden[hidden <= 0] = 0
```

Gives me the error:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 10
```

More info:

```
 print(type(hidden))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
 print(type(hidden))

<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
print(dhidden.shape)
(5, 3)
 print(hidden.shape)
(5, 10)
```

hidden.dtype and dhidden.dtype are float64

I tried     dhidden[hidden <= 0.0] = 0.0 and still get the same error.

Comment: `hidden` and `dhidden` have different shapes, as you can clearly see. They aren't compatible. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve by using one as a mask for the other?

Comment: applying ReLU here as for activation function. d here represents the gradient.

Comment: No, no. What you're not explaining is why these two arrays have different shapes, when you expect to use them like that. The error is clear, the arrays have different shapes.

Answer (score 0):

The indices, that the Boolean evaluation for `hidden`, return are out of the bounds of `dhidden`. It may thus be the case that a result of the expression returns an index 4, 9 which is out of the bounds of `dhidden`. The dimensions of dhidden can be greater than those of hidden, but not the other way around. If you wanted only the relevant values of `hidden` you could try the following:

`dhidden[hidden[:, :3] <=0] = 0`

Per @Reti43's suggestion: It is important to note that this assumes that only first 3 columns are relevant from hidden.

Comment: We lack important context to say whether slicing the array will work. Sure, programmatically it does. But are you *actually* working on data you meant to be working?